# The color bar at bottom of button is not displaying correctly in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

The color bar at bottom of my nav buttons is not displaying correctly in Firefox. It displays great in Mac Chrome, Mac Safari, PC IE 10. But not Mac Firefox (v. 19.0.2)

http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/CEXts/

```
 #navMenu ul, #navMenu {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
```

Is anyone able to assist me with this? Your help is much appreciated!

Trevor

Comment: Please define "Not displaying correctly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the padding on the anchor tags. Remove the padding and it should display correctly. But I suggest that you set the bottom border style on the surrounding li-element. Because otherwise the bottom border will not be as wide as the li in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

remove this property

```
.nav > li > a { height:100% ; ... }
```